# Raspberry Pi Zero W bluetooth connecting and disconnecting

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi zero W to my pixel 7 phone.  I can pair and connect for about 3 seconds then it disconnects.  Ive trusted my phone, still nothing.

I am running Raspbian OS, headless.  Have checked for and installed updates every day.  I am using bluez 5.37, even rolled it back to the last stable version, tried different phones, same result.

I see this has been an issue with bluez for some time (years).  Any help you can provide?  Is there another bluetooth package I can download and use?  Thanks.

Comment: After you have done the pairing you haven't said what application you are using on your phone to connect to what Bluetooth service on the RPi. It sounds like you are just doing the pairing where it only stays connected long enough to exchange keys and then disconnects. If you want a Classic serial connection then run this example on the RPi https://github.com/martinohanlon/BlueDot/blob/master/examples/server_debug.py and use an app like the following on the phone: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal

Comment: @ukBaz thanks.  Im using the android bluetooth connections.  I did fail to mention that after the first connection, it won't reconnect.  I have to forget it from phone and start over.  I downloaded the app you recommended and still the same.  Any ideas?

Comment: What you are describing sounds like the correct behaviour when services on both ends of the Bluetooth link are not matching. On the RPi do `bluetoothctl show` to see what services (UUIDs) are listed. Then see what services are on your phone with `bluetoothctl info <your phones mac address>` (You can get your phones mac address with `bluetoothctl devices`. To get more debug information have `sudo btmon` running when you try to connect to see why it is being rejected. `wireshark` can help make the BT snoop log more readable.